# Unselect an Android View when selecting another one

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have 4 ImageView's inside a LinearLayout. There is also a selector.xml file that sets background color red when android:state_selected="true"

What I want is to have **only** one view selected. I don't know how I can keep a reference to the last selected view so I can unselected it.

The code I have so far is :

```
        ImageView beer = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.beer_button);
    ImageView coffee = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.coffee_button);
    ImageView food = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.food_button);
    ImageView wifi = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.wifi_button);

    beer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()   {
           public void onClick(View v)     {
               Log.v("flag", "1");
               v.setSelected(true);
           }
    });



    coffee.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v)     {
               Log.v("flag", "2");
               v.setSelected(true);
           }
    });

    food.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()   {
           public void onClick(View v)     {
               Log.v("flag", "3");
               v.setSelected(true);
           }
    });

    wifi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()   {
           public void onClick(View v)     {
               Log.v("flag", "4");
               v.setSelected(true);
           }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Radiogroup and don't worry about selected state. Or when select image deselect ones.

Use radiogroup is best way:
1. you don't duplicate code.
2. any time you can get selected item.

Comment: How I know which one to deselect?

Comment: when select keep ref to selected item. But use radiogroup is more prefer in this case.

Comment: I will change it to RadioGroup. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
water.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()   {
       public void onClick(View v)     {
           Log.v("flag", "0");
           ((LinearLayout)v.getParent()).dispatchSetSelected(false);
           v.setSelected(true);
       }
});
```

Comment: or `((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).dispatchSetSelected(false);`

Answer (score -1):

Besides @slientnuke's answer, you can also do something like this:

```
// First define imageViews as global
private ImageView beer, coffee, food, wifi;

// Find them and set their click event to one
beer = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.beer_button);
coffee = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.coffee_button);
food = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.food_button);
wifi = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.wifi_button);

beer.setOnClickListener(selectionListener);
coffee.setOnClickListener(selectionListener);
food.setOnClickListener(selectionListener);
wifi.setOnClickListener(selectionListener);

// Define selectionListener
private OnClickListener selectionListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        beer.setSelected(false);
        coffee.setSelected(false);
        food.setSelected(false);
        wifi.setSelected(false);

        v.setSelected(true);
    }

};
```